JSON object uploaded successfully to MONGODB using express however console logging an error
I am recently creating a server which handles CRUD operation in expressJS , I have constructed 2 schemas namely user and note , user controllers are working as intended whereas although note controller working as intended the console is logging error which I am unable to identify , any help on why the this error is being raised would be appreciated .
NoteSchema :
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose)

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user_id : {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required : true,
            ref : 'user'
        },
        title : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        text : {
            type : String,
            required : true
        },
        completed : {
            type : Boolean,
            required : true
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps : true
    } 
)

noteSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement , {
    inc_field : 'ticket',
    id : 'ticketNums',
    start_seq : 600
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('note' , noteSchema)


Note Creation controller :
const createNewNote = asyncHandler(async (req , res) => {
    const {user_id , title , text , completed} = req.body

    console.log(user + title + text + completed)
    if(!user_id || !title || !text || typeof completed !== 'boolean'){
        return res.status(400).json({msg : "Bad request : all fields are required"})
    }

    const exists = await note.findOne({title}).lean().exec()

    if(exists){
        return res.status(400).json({msg : "Bad request record already exists"})
    }

    const userfound = await user.findById(user_id).lean().exec()

    if(!userfound){
        return res.status(400).json({msg : "user id assigned to note doesnt exist"})
    }

    
    const noteobj = {user_id , title , text , completed}
    
    const result = await note.create(noteobj)

    if(result){
        return res.status(200).json({msg : `record has been uploaded`})
    }
    res.status(400).json({msg : "Uncaught error"})
})

Console :
Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Watching directory 'C:\work\DEV\MERN (personal)\tech notes\backend' for changes.
Press rs for restarting the process.
development
Connected to DB
listening to port  3500
POST /notes/
function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
      model.hooks.execPreSync('createModel', doc);
      if (!(this instanceof model)) {
        return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
      }
      const discriminatorKey = model.schema.options.discriminatorKey;

      if (model.discriminators == null || doc == null || doc[discriminatorKey] == null) {
        Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
        return;
      }

      // If discriminator key is set, use the discriminator instead (gh-7586)
      const Discriminator = model.discriminators[doc[discriminatorKey]] ||
        getDiscriminatorByValue(model.discriminators, doc[discriminatorKey]);
      if (Discriminator != null) {
        return new Discriminator(doc, fields, skipId);
      }

      // Otherwise, just use the top-level model
      Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
    }

Kindly note that the note(record) is being uploaded to MongoDB successfully although the console is logging an error
Tried looking up errors but to no avail and tried logging but to no avail , I am using this logger middleware for logging :
const {format} = require('date-fns')
const {v4 : uuid} = require('uuid')
const fs = require('fs')
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises
const path = require('path')

const logEvents = async (message , logFileName) =>{
    const dateTime = format(new Date(), 'yyyyMMdd\tHH:mm:ss')
    const logItem = `${dateTime}\t${uuid()}\t${message}\n`

    try{
        if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'logs'))) {
            await fsPromises.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'logs'))
        }
        await fsPromises.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'logs', logFileName), logItem)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

const logger = (req , res , next)=>{
    logEvents(`${req.method}\t${req.url}\t${req.headers.origin}`, 'reqLog.log')
    console.log(`${req.method} ${req.path}`)
    next()
}

module.exports = {logEvents , logger}


It would be user_id not user inside console.log()

It would be easier to answer if the error message was included in the question
